# Rasterio doesn't display the differnet bands of image

Tags: python, rasterio, digital-image-processing, band

I have one raster which has three different bands.

The two first bands look like this (in qgis):

[image]

and the third band looks like this ( missing values in some places:

[image]

The three bands sit on top of each other.
The problem is that whenever I try todisplay those layers with  rasterio it always shows the "extent" of the third layer:

```
img=rasterio.open("21072019.tif")
show(img,1)

#display other bands:
show(img,2)

show(img,3)
```

[image]

with all those bands the image looks exactly the same, th eonly thing that changes is the axis.

**My question: How can I display the different bands? why is this hapenning? do the difffeernt bands has different shape?**